# Customizing NSIS installer using CPACK

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I am trying to customize an NSIS installer using CMAKE and CPACK.
In particular I would like to include in the generated project.nsi an external script.

Something like:

```
!include "@SCRIPT_PATH@\@SCRIPT_NAME@.nsh"
```

To do so I am following the example shown here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/NSISAdvancedTips

I have copied the template script file (NSIS.template.in) and added the required commands.
I now need to configure the two variables "@SCRIPT_PATH@ and @SCRIPT_NAME@ accordingly.

I tried to set them like standard CMAKE variables

```
SET(SCRIPT_PATH "somePath")
SET(SCRIPT_NAME "someName")
```

but the template variables are simply left blank by CPACK

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution.

Start by adding a placeholder in the main NSIS.template.in where you want to insert new commands, for instance:

```
@NSIS_ADDITIONAL_SCRIPT@
```

Then you need to configure a template file containing options that will be passed to the CPACK build.

The CPackOptions.cmake contains the following:

```
SET(NSIS_ADDITIONAL_SCRIPT ${NSIS_ADDITIONAL_SCRIPT})
```

Then in your CMAKE script before including CPACK you need to set the NSIS_ADDITIONAL_SCRIPT variable (the path is reworked in order to have the correct set of backslashes on window systems)

```
SET(scriptPath "[path to the script location]" )
FILE(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${scriptPath} scriptPath )
STRING(REPLACE "\\" "\\\\" scriptPath  ${scriptPath} )
```

and finally configure the CPackOption.cmake file (watch out for the correct number of slashes and comas)

```
SET(NSIS_ADDITIONAL_SCRIPT " \"!include \\\"${scriptPath}\\\" \\n  \" ")
CONFIGURE_FILE( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeConf/CPackOptions.cmake ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CPackOptions.cmake)
```

If you do everything correctly:

- by configuring and generating the CMAKE script you will find the file CPackOptions.cmake in your project build folder.
- This configured file will be then used by CPACK to fill in the variable added in the NSIStemplate.in.
- The final generated project.nsi will contain the additional !include instruction

Comment: Does this work for cmake 3.20? I tried, but the variable within the template.in file will be removed and stays blank

Comment: @SimonPio. It seems like a problem with variables not being escpaed properly. Can you give some details about your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it may help some folks out there:

The solution to your problem is to prefix your variables, `SCRIPT_PATH` and `SCRIPT_NAME` by `CPACK`. So that it will be `CPACK_SCRIPT_PATH`...

That way when CMake process your CmakeLists it knows that your variables should be set for CPack (in other word when generating CPackConfig.cmake).