# Cpack NSIS can not signing the uninstaller

Tags: c++, cmake, nsis, uninstallation, cpack

I have a cross-platform application that is developed with C++. CMake is used as a build tool.

I am having a problem with code signing in CPACK/NSIS. I could sign the installer that was created by CPACK/NSIS.

So far everything is good. But I could not sign to uninstaller by using CPACK.

I have also tried the NSIS guide which is [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Signing_an_Uninstaller). It does not help me because of I want to use CPACK for the other installing parts.

Comment: I don't know about signing however I do know that you can modify the template that CPack uses for NSIS. I have customized mine years ago to add some functionality. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144655/customizing-nsis-installer-using-cpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144655/customizing-nsis-installer-using-cpack) with this said I am not sure if the procedure has changed in modern CMake.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Because your solution is just inserting the NSIS script. It defines a new section. My need is to change the section related to the uninstaller.  I guess I should write my template NSIS script from zero. Thank you for your suggestion.